# Java sources in idea

Tags: intellij-idea

In idea when I open type with Ctrl+N it opens by default class file without sources attached. However there is src zip in sources path of JDK. When I open class through Ctrl+Shift+N I have a possibility to choose source or class file. Why I can't open source file of class directly with Ctrl+N

Answer (score 0):

When you open that class there should be an option at the top of the editor asking you to attach sources (or even download them in case of maven dependencies). Clicking that link will open a file browser where you find and select the zip-file.

This adds the zip file as a source for that dependency and from now on classes from that dependency will show it's source.

Comment: I did exactly as you descibed, but it's rather tedious to do that for each class I open